# Missing delimiter (. inserted). That mistake showed up when I try to compile the code below, What's wrong with it?

Tags: equations, babel, delimiters, missing, russian

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage{mathtext}               % русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы

%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление

%% Номера формул
%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.

%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Красивый матшрифт

%% Свои команды
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{\mathop{sgn}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
%% Перенос знаков в формулах (по Львовскому)
\newcommand*{\hm}[1]{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}
    {\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt #1$}}{}}

%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Для вставки рисунков
\usepackage{caption
}
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} % Отступ рамки \fbox{} от рисунка
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt} % Толщина линий рамки \fbox{}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Обтекание рисунков и таблиц текстом
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
%%% Работа с таблицами
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs} % Дополнительная работа с таблицами
\usepackage{longtable}  % Длинные таблицы
\usepackage{multirow} % Слияние строк в таблице

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
        $ \dfrac{1}{\rho_1^3}$ & = & $\dfrac{1}{\rho^3} \left 1 + 3\dfrac{L}{T+L}  \cos\omega + (\dfrac{L}{T+L}  r)^2  (-\dfrac{3}{2} +\dfrac{15}{2}\cos^2\omega) + \dots \right $  \\
    $ \dfrac{1}{\rho_2 ^3}$ & = & $\dfrac{1}{\rho^3} \left  1 +3 \dfrac{T}{T+L}  \cos\omega + (\dfrac{T}{T+L}  r)^2(-\dfrac{3}{2} + \dfrac{15}{2}\cos^2\omega) + \dots\  \right$ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could have posted a much smaller example. You need a delimiter after `\left` so `\left (`  or delete `\left`. Similarly `\right)` or delete `\right`

Comment: You should use a display math environment such as `align*` here not a `tabular` but that is unrelated to the error.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidCarlisle has noted in a comment, you *must* supply a delimiter symbol with `\left` and `\right`. I suggest you supply `[` and `]`, respectively. You should also increase the sizes of the `(` and `)` delimiters in the equations, by supplying the prefixes `\biggl` and `\biggr`, respectively. And, as @DavidCarlisle has further pointed out, you should use an `align*` environment, not an `array` environment, to typeset the two equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\rho_1 ^3} &= \frac{1}{\rho^3} \biggl[
1 + 3\frac{L}{T+L}  \cos\omega + \biggl(\frac{L}{T+L}\,r \biggr)^{\!\!2}  
   \biggl(-\frac{3}{2} + \frac{15}{2}\cos^2\omega \biggr) + \dotsb \biggr] \\[1ex]
\frac{1}{\rho_2 ^3} &= \frac{1}{\rho^3} \biggl[  
1 +3 \frac{T}{T+L}  \cos\omega + \biggl(\frac{T}{T+L}\,r \biggr)^{\!\!2} 
   \biggl(-\frac{3}{2} + \frac{15}{2}\cos^2\omega \biggr) + \dotsb \biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```